# Prove that the Archimedes property doesn't occur in the Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, proof-explanation, relations, order-theory

I found this question and I can't solve it.

So by Definition of Archimedes property - Archimedes property doesn't occur if The $\mathbb{N}$ set is bounded.

Which means - this is what we need to prove - that $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded over Polynomials.

My try :

**Prove by contradiction:**

Lets assume that $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded over $P(x)$ which means exist $n∈\mathbb{N}$:

such that :
$∀P(x) : P(x)<n$

$n∈\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}⊆\mathbb{R}$ $\Rightarrow$ $n∈\mathbb{R}$.

Lets take the polynomial $P(x)=x+1$ and do $P(n)=n+1$ and by assumption $n+1<n$
which is a contradiction.

Which means $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded above $P(x)$ $\Rightarrow$ The polynomials doesn't "have" the archimedes axiom.

is it ok to assume that ? or I did a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That problem only makes sense if we define an order relation on the polynomials. The usual one is this: $p(x)<q(x)$ if one of these conditions holds:

1. $\deg p(x)<\deg q(x)$
2. $\deg p(x)=\deg q(x)$ and, if $n$ is that common degree, then the coefficient of $x^n$ in $p(x)$ is smaller than the coefficient of $x^n$ in $q(x)$.

With this definition, it is clear that $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):n<x$. So, indeed, the Archimedes property doesn't hold in this context.

Comment: I forgot to mention , my Order relation is - if the coefficient of the biggest degree $P(x)-G(x)>0$. why "it is clear that $(∀n∈N):n<x$"

Comment: Because the coefficient with biggest degree in $x-n$ is $1$ and $1>0$.

Comment: so this means , every polynomial in that order relation > every constant polynomial $p(x)=n∈\mathbb{N}$. which means , $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded in that relation $\Rightarrow$ archimedes axiom doesn't occur ? I got that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much!